# Python Click: RuntimeError when passing object into command

Tags: python, spotipy

I have my code set up in the following way:

```py
import spotipy as sp
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials, SpotifyOAuth
import click


pass_auth_obj = click.make_pass_decorator(sp.client.Spotify)


@click.group()
def main():
    pass


@main.command()
@click.option(
    "--clientid",
    "-ci",
    "client_id",
    required=True,
    type=str,
    envvar="SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID",
)
@click.option(
    "--clientsecret",
    "-cs",
    "client_secret",
    required=True,
    type=str,
    envvar="SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET",
)
@click.option(
    "--redirecturl",
    "-rd",
    "redirect_uri",
    required=True,
    type=str,
    envvar="SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI",
)
@click.pass_context
def connect(ctx, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri):
    try:
        ctx.obj = sp.Spotify(
            auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
                client_id=client_id,
                client_secret=client_secret,
                redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                open_browser=False,
            )
        )
        click.secho("API authorization successful!", fg="green")
    except:
        click.secho("API authorization failed!", fg="red")


@main.command()
@pass_auth_obj
def play_random_saved_album(sp_auth):

    # Only 50 albums can be retrieved at a time, so make as many requests as necessary to retrieve
    # all in library.
    saved_albums = []
    offset = 0
    while True:
        albums_res = sp_auth.current_user_saved_albums(limit=50, offset=offset)
```

I've cut off the end of the `play_random_saved_album` command, but this is the first instance where I try to use the object that I am passing through.

As I understand it, in order to pass a custom class object from one command to another, I need to create a new pass decorator and use that. However, when I run `poetry run spoticli play_random_saved_album`, I get the following error (this is after successfully making a connection with `poetry run spoticli connect)`:

```
▶ poetry run spoticli connect                
API authorization successful!
(Python venv-spoticli) 
GitHub Repos/spoticli/spoticli  spoticli_add_basic_functionality ✗  
▶ poetry run spoticli play-random-saved-album
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joe-linux/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/venv-spoticli/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 78, in new_func
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Managed to invoke callback without a context object of type 'Spotify' existing.
```

How do I correct my implementation to avoid the RuntimeError?

Thanks!

Comment: as for me your problem is that `spoticli connect` creates connection but end of script has to close connection - and you can't change it. And when you run `spoticli play_random_saved_album` then it runs new process which doesn't have connection. You have to run connection inside `play_random_saved_album`. Everytime when you execute `spoticli` you have to again create connection.

Comment: @furas thanks for the response! That's interesting, I would've thought because it's just an authorization object that it wouldn't terminate once the `connect` method is done running. I'll give that a shot instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following the clue from Furas in the comment on my original problem statement, I decided to break the `connect` command out into a separate function. A nice side effect of doing this is that I'm now able to specify the scope for each command rather than using a blanket statement scope for a single authorization.

Here's my implementation that seems to work well:

```py
def connect(
    scope,
    client_id=SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri=SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI,
):
    try:
        auth = sp.Spotify(
            auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
                scope=scope,
                client_id=client_id,
                client_secret=client_secret,
                redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
            )
        )
    except:
        click.secho(
            "API authorization failed! Did you remember to set the environment variables?",
            fg="red",
        )

    return auth

@main.command()
def play_random_saved_album():

    # Only 50 albums can be retrieved at a time, so make as many requests as necessary to retrieve
    # all in library.
    sp_auth = connect(scope="user-library-read user-modify-playback-state")
```

Interested to see if anyone has any other thoughts about how to handle this specific case with `click`!